# Stubbing AWS S3 object request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, testing, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-ruby

I'm trying to stub out a request to get an object in a AWS bucket. I've read their docs about stubbing requests and was only able to stub out a bucket, not an object. Here are somethings I've tried:

Stubbing through the AWS config:

```
Aws.config[:s3] = {
  stub_responses: {
    list_buckets: {
      buckets: [name: "my-bucket"],
      list_objects: [key: "file.pdf"]
    }
  }
}
```

While that got the bucket, it did not give me the object. Calling `s3.buckets` would list the bucket, but `s3.objects` would be empty.

Stubbing through `webmock` gem:

```
tempfile = file_fixture('file.pdf').read
base_uri = Regexp.new "https://my-bucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.
stub_request(:get, base_uri).to_return(status: 200, body: tempfile)
```

This still doesn't seem to work. Calling `bucket.objects` still returns an empty collection.

The code in my controller I want to test:

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
bucket = s3.bucket("my-bucket")
@files = {}

bucket.objects.each do |item|
  @files[File.basename(item.key)] = item.presigned_url(:get)
end
```

The goal is I want to make sure my view shows the links to the objects in my `@file` variable and I want to test that link. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm new to developing with AWS S3 and googlge haven't been much help. I'm using the `aws-sdk-s3` gem to work with AWS S3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out. I also needed to stub out the `#list_objects` method in order to get the objects. The final stub would look something like this:

```
Aws.config[:s3] = {
  stub_responses: {
    list_buckets: {
      buckets: [name: "my-bucket"]
    },
    list_objects: {
      contents: [{key: "mykey"}]
    },
    get_object: {
      body: file_fixture('file').read
    }
  }
}
```

Now if I do `s3.buckets.first.objects.first` I would get back the stubbed object.

Comment: Saved me a lot of time. Thanks!

Comment: That works for me!. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your question and answer! You may want to add `list_objects_v2` as a stubbed function (same body as `list_objects`). That made it work for me, thanks again.